# If only one child (li#inThis), remove self (ul#section)

Tags: jquery

How can I set `display:none` to a `ul` if only has a single child?

This `ul` would be hidden, because it only has one `li`

```
<ul id="section">
  <li id="inThis">In this section:</li>
</ul>
```

But this `ul` would not be hidden, because there are multiple `li`s

```
<ul id="section">
   <li id="inThis">In this section:</li>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
if($("#section li").length == 1)
{
   $("#section").hide();
}
```

Comment: @redsquare That's why I do hate JavaScript ;-)

Answer (score 7):

```
$("ul li:only-child").parent().hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

//this is one way

```
if($('#section li').length == 1){
  $j(this).parent().css('display', 'none');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//This will match only elements of li type as the only child.

```
$("ul li:only-of-type").parent().hide();
```